Torque Motor. Need advice for pole count and windings
I taught myself the basics of motor design and am about to build a torque motor with 20 Nm constant torque and 500 RPM, BLDC 48-72 V, hollow shaft 105 mm, 60 mm length.

I saw several images of torque motors with 27 slots and 24 poles. Is this really the best combination for torque, current, etc? What about 36 slots, 42,.....?

I have no idea how to determine wire gauge and winding count, maybe someone can give me some advice.



does anyone have a rough estimation? I tried to find infos on the web but nothing concrete that lets me understand how to proceed.
